# Obstacle Avoidance in DJI Mobile SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, dji-sdk, drone.io

I am working with dronelink sdk from https://github.com/dronelink/dronelink-dji-example-android.git In this example, there is no obstacle avoidance feature be implemented. How can I add that feature to this project? Hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The DroneLink SDK is not a release by DJI so you are unlikely to receive an answer as you have tagged the question.  My suggestion would be to visit the Git repository for the project and post your question under the [issues section](https://github.com/dronelink/dronelink-dji-example-android/issues).  You may have better luck getting your answer from the developer than the general community.